# When I create an new article in Joomla, how do I drop the "/joomla" from the URL?

Tags: url, joomla, categories, joomla-article

When I create a new article at `https://www.example.com` the new article comes in the form `https://www.example.com/joomla/1-category/1-article-number`

What can I do so that Joomla drops the "/joomla" and the category and article numbers?

Comment: i don't want to drop the category and article name entirely. i just want to drop the /joomla and the numbers that precede the category and article name. i want to keep the categories because i have another page on the site that does a search by the category.

Comment: What have you already tried? More people will be able to help you if you show what steps you have already taken. Please see how to ask a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You shouldn't normally have a joomla in your url unless you are in a subfolder or something. It's not a normal structure to always have the word Joomla.

Comment: I've tried enabling the SEF option in global configuration and editing the .htaccess file in Apache. When i change the directory to /htdocs folder i get 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is really has to be taken from top level of category where you put article, just change it to whatever and you good

Answer (score 0):

This is due to menu or category aliases, for example you have an article in menu item

```
> Joomla > Category 1 > Article
```

You can make it top level (Parent) so it will become like

http://yoursite.com/article

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to remove it. Bitnami has a tool assuming you've already changed the .htaccess file on your apache server.

http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Joomla!_Stack

the sudo command on the remote server is:

$ sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/updateip --appurl /